# CamVid12 Image Segmentation Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, image-segmentation

I'm trying to train an image segmentation model on the CamVid dataset. I noticed a couple papers (ESPNet and SegNet) both used a condensed version of the CamVid dataset (12 classes instead of 32).

I can't find the labels for the 12 class version of the dataset. The [SegNet tutorial](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/tree/master/CamVid) contains masks where black is the void class and everything else is one color.

Is there a dataset readily available with the 12 class masks? Or is there a breakdown of how the 32 classes were converted to 12? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/lih627/CamVid
Contains a breakdown of the original 32 -> 12 classes.